# Mercurial: See how often a branch merges with and from default

Tags: mercurial

Let´s say I have two branches, default and mybranch, I would like to write a small script to see:

1. How often mybranch merges with default (changes goes from mybranch to default)
2. How often mybranch merges from default (changes goes from default into mybranch)

Some pseudocode for #1:

```
    m_lastmergetime = 0
    for each m in [all merges with default from mybranch]
        m_mergetime = m.date_in_hours
        m_timebetweenmerges = m_mergetime - m_lastmergetime
        if m_lastmergetime > 0
            print m_timebetweenmerges
```

Sub.steps:

1. A Mercurial query which matches all merges with default from mybranch
2. A style for Mercurial which shows the date in hours
3. Calculate the time between merges as in the above pseudocode using Bash or Python

Case #2 will be pretty similar. I only need:

1. A Mercurial query which matches all merges with mybranch from default

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To find all the changesets on branch X that was merged in from branch Y you would issue the following Mercurial command:

```
hg log --rev "children(branch(X)) and children(branch(Y)) and branch(X)"
```

To find everything on branch Y that was merged in from branch X (ie. the opposite direction), simply change the last branch name there to Y:

```
hg log --rev "children(branch(X)) and children(branch(Y)) and branch(Y)"
                              ^                       ^              ^
                              +------ leave these ----+              |
                                                                     |
                                      but change this ---------------+
```

Basically the query says that you want all changesets that:

- is a child of any of the changesets on branch X
- is also a child of any of the changesets on branch Y (only merge changesets have two parents, and can thus be a child of changesets on two branches at the same time)
- is *on* branch Y (so you merged *to* branch Y)

Comment: I know I left out some parts of your question, like the part about dates, "how often", "how many", etc. not entirely sure how to do that in bash anyway so if someone has that part of the answer, feel free to pilfer my answer for whatever pertinent details you need and repost a better answer, after all that's how Stack Overflow works :)

Comment: One gets unix time stamps of the merges by appending `--template '{date|hgdate}\n'` to the log commands. From that on, getting the time between merges shouldn't be a problem. If it is, it's worth an own question.

Comment: #1 was by far the most important one. I don´t think anyone will provide more help to this question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Oben! That makes it almost complete. I can create that Bash script myself! :-)

Comment: Set myself the challenge to see if I could get a revset query for this before checking if someone had answered it. I got it, but yours is cleaner :) (you only had to change one thing to switch perspectives). I'm continually amazed by how expressive revsets are!

Comment: Can you limit query to a changeset range?

Comment: Yes, just append " and 1::10"